# marshalling a struct with char* to C#

Tags: c#, struct, pinvoke

I have the following struct used in a C program

```
typedef enum
{
  ndberror_st_success = 0,
  ndberror_st_temporary = 1,
  ndberror_st_permanent = 2,
  ndberror_st_unknown = 3
} ndberror_status_enum;

typedef enum
{
 ndberror_cl_none = 0,  
 ndberror_cl_application = 1,  
 ndberror_cl_no_data_found = 2,
 ndberror_cl_constraint_violation = 3,
 ndberror_cl_schema_error = 4,
 ndberror_cl_user_defined = 5,
 ndberror_cl_insufficient_space = 6,
 ndberror_cl_temporary_resource = 7,
 ndberror_cl_node_recovery = 8,
 ndberror_cl_overload = 9,
 ndberror_cl_timeout_expired = 10,
 ndberror_cl_unknown_result = 11,
 ndberror_cl_internal_error = 12,
 ndberror_cl_function_not_implemented = 13,
 ndberror_cl_unknown_error_code = 14,
 ndberror_cl_node_shutdown = 15,
 ndberror_cl_configuration = 16,
 ndberror_cl_schema_object_already_exists = 17,
 ndberror_cl_internal_temporary = 18
} ndberror_classification_enum;


typedef struct {
  ndberror_status_enum status;
  ndberror_classification_enum classification;
  int code;
  int mysql_code;
  const char * message;
  char * details;
} ndberror_struct;
```

I need to marshal it in a c# program, the C# side declaration is:

```
    public enum ndberror_status
    {
        ndberror_st_success = 0,
        ndberror_st_temporary = 1,
        ndberror_st_permanent = 2,
        ndberror_st_unknown = 3,
    }

    public enum ndberror_classification
    {
        ndberror_cl_none = 0,
        ndberror_cl_application = 1,
        ndberror_cl_no_data_found = 2,
        ndberror_cl_constraint_violation = 3,
        ndberror_cl_schema_error = 4,
        ndberror_cl_user_defined = 5,
        ndberror_cl_insufficient_space = 6,
        ndberror_cl_temporary_resource = 7,
        ndberror_cl_node_recovery = 8,
        ndberror_cl_overload = 9,
        ndberror_cl_timeout_expired = 10,
        ndberror_cl_unknown_result = 11,
        ndberror_cl_internal_error = 12,
        ndberror_cl_function_not_implemented = 13,
        ndberror_cl_unknown_error_code = 14,
        ndberror_cl_node_shutdown = 15,
        ndberror_cl_configuration = 16,
        ndberror_cl_schema_object_already_exists = 17,
        ndberror_cl_internal_temporary = 18,
    }
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ndberror_struct
    {      
        public ndberror_status status;
        public ndberror_classification classification;
        public int code;
        public int mysql_code;
       [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string message;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string details;
    }
```

The C-Side signature of the method to be called is:

```
const ndberror_struct __stdcall Ndb_getNdbError(void* obj);
```

The C#-Side instead is:

```
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("Ndb_CWrapper.dll", EntryPoint = "Ndb_getNdbError", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall,CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern ndberror_struct Ndb_getNdbError(System.IntPtr obj);
```

When i try to invoke the method from the managed code a MarshalDirectiveException raises.
I think the problem is somewhere in the string marshalling, but i'm not able to solve the problem.
The native library is compiled for a x64 system multibyte charset code (with visual studio c++ 2012)

The alternative can be some strange operation inside the native code, where i cast a `NdbError` (defined in another header) to `ndberror_struct`, here the code:

```
Ndb* tmp=(Ndb*)obj;
ndberror_struct tmpRes=(ndberror_struct)tmp->getNdbError();
```

The `NdbStruct` returned by `tmp->getNdbError()` overload the casting operator (i suppose), this is the declaration:

```
operator ndberror_struct() const {
    ndberror_struct ndberror;
    ndberror.status = (ndberror_status_enum) status;
    ndberror.classification = (ndberror_classification_enum) classification;
    ndberror.code = code;
    ndberror.mysql_code = mysql_code;
    ndberror.message = message;
    ndberror.details = details;
    return ndberror;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
I tried to change a bit the method's signature in this way:
C-Side:

```
void* __stdcall Ndb_getNdbError(void* obj)
```

C#-Side:

```
IntPtr Ndb_getNdbError(IntPtr obj)
```

the native method return `&tmpRes` and in the managed code i had marshalled manually the struct calling

```
var tmp=Ndb_getNdbError(raw);
var f = (ndberror_struct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(tmp, typeof(ndberror_struct));
```

Comment: What message (text) do you get with the `MarshalDirectiveException`?

Comment: The message says: Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The marshaller won't marshal those `char*` fields from the native code to the managed. You'll have to do that bit yourself.

One way to do that is to change the C# struct declaration as follows:

```
public struct ndberror_struct
{      
    public ndberror_status status;
    public ndberror_classification classification;
    public int code;
    public int mysql_code;
    public IntPtr message;
    public IntPtr details;
}
```

Leave your p/invoke declaration as it is:

```
[DllImport("Ndb_CWrapper.dll")]
private static extern ndberror_struct Ndb_getNdbError(IntPtr obj);
```

You'll be able to call the function now. In order to convert the two `IntPtr` fields into strings, call `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi`.

Comment: i think i will do as you suggested, in this way i don't need to change the signature of the native code

Comment: Out of interest, who deallocates the strings?

Comment: Up to now i cannot give you the right answer because i really don't know. I am at the early stage of creating a wrapper from the NDB API provided by Oracle (MYSQL): the library is written in C++, i need to make a double wrapper from C++ to C and after from C to C#. So for this strings and surely for other furter things i need to take care of the deallocating

Comment: If the target code is C++ then single C++/CLI wrapper sounds best

Comment: Unfortunately I need 2 wrapper, one wrapper for pure C code/compiler and one for C# so in this way i should take 2 birds with one stone...i hope

Comment: If you wrote a C++/CLI wrapper then you'd need only one wrapper. Do you need more help with the question you asked here?

Comment: I understand what you mean, the only thing i don't understand is how i can use the wrapper in a pure ANSI C enviroment, i have other developers that need an ANSI C library. Btw any help will be appreciated, this is my first time with wrappers

Comment: If the C code can be compiled with Microsoft's somewhat lame C compiler then you can use a mixed mode C++/CLI assembly to compile the C code. You can then wrap it and expose it to the C# code as a managed C++ ref class which can be consumed by C#. By the way, are you wanting more help with the question that you asked here?

Comment: Gimme the time to try your solution, just 5 minutes

Comment: Ok the solution seems to work. Unfortunately the C code must be compiled on embedded devices running linux

Comment: OK, I understand that. So it sounds like you do need wrappers a-plenty. I was just trying to explore the possibility of simplifying things for you.

Comment: I really appreciate it